# How to get user ID (FOSUserBundle) in form builder in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm quite new here, be patient, please.

I'm trying to make notice board project in Symfony2 using FOSUserBundle.
I try to get logged user id to put it into form created with form builder (and then to MySQL database).
One of attempts  is:

```
public function createNoticeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $notice = new Notice();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($notice)
            ->add("content", "text")
            ->add("user_id","entity",
                array("class"=>"FOS/UserBundle/FOSUserBundle:", "choice_label"=>"id"))
            ->add("isActive", "true")
            ->add("category", "entity",
                array("class" => "AppBundle:Category", "choice_label" => "name"))
            ->add("save", "submit", array("label" => "Save"))
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($notice);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_showuserpage');
    }
```

I tried many solutions again and again and  I get some error.

Comment: Why user_id class ends as FOSUserBundle: ?

Comment: M'm trying many options, this is one of many, I tried just FOSUserBundle and it didn't work.

Comment: What I ment is that it must be something as FOSUserBundle:User not just FOSUserBundle: .. you are missing the class name of your entity..

Comment: I try this:            ->add("user_id","entity",
                array("class"=>"FOSUserBundle:User", "choice_label"=>"id"))  and            ->add("user_id","entity",
                array("class"=>"FOS/UserBundle/FOSUserBundle:User", "choice_label"=>"id"))  - still doesn't work

Comment: "some error" is never descriptive. Always write *the exact error* that is shown.

Comment: example: 
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'FOS/UserBundle/FOSUserBundle'.

Comment: Where does your User entity lays? - Can be seen in security.yml - to which entity encoder(-s) is/are configured?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the user object Symfony > 2.1.x

In you Controller like this:

```
$userId = $this->getUser()->getId();
...
$notice->setUserId($userId);
$em->persist($notice);
```

Don't `->add` field in you FormBuilder, its not safely. Set this value in you Controller and don't `->add` this field in FormBuilder

Answer (score 0):

for symfony 3.2.13

have excelent solution (just because is working, but is dangerous if someone discover it in pure HTML)

1) first build YourFormType class.

add normal field in Forms/YourFormType.php (if not, formbuilder tell you that you passing smth not quite right (too many fields) ; -) )

```
$builder
            ->add(
                'MyModelAddedById',
                HiddenType::class,
                [
                'label' => 'echhh', //somehow it has to be here
                'attr' => ['style' => 'display:none'], //somehow it has to be here
                ]
    );
```

2) in your controller

```
public function addSomethingAction(Request $request){

$form = $this->createForm(MyModelFormType::class);

//set field value
$request->request->set("prodModelAddedById", $this->getUser()->getId());

$form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $product = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);

            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'record was added');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('products');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'default.add.form.html.twig',
            [
                'newprod' => $form->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
```

explenation:

you are passing a field and variable to formbuilder (settig it already to default value!)

and important thing, becose of BUG in my opinion - you can't in your form type set method:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    //return 'app_bundle_my_form_type';
}


because 
$request->request->set
```

can't work properly if your POST data from form are in bag (parameterbag)

no entity managers, no services, no listeners...

hope it helps.